# Applying Universal Instantiation to ∀xP(x) → ∀xQ(x)

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

I understand if i have:
∀x(P(x) → Q(x))

Applying Universal Instantiation i have:

P(c) → Q(c)

as ∀x is bound to both P(x) and Q(x).

I'm struggling to understand how i'd apply Universal Instantiation to:

∀xP(x) → ∀xQ(x)

Obviously it cannot be P(c) → Q(c), but i'm unsure how i'd represent it.
Some lines of thought i had were, using a second arbitrary constant say d:

P(c) → Q(d)

However this seems wrong to me, as c and d are both arbitrary constants so represent the same thing. Another thing i was thinking was something like:

(P(c)) → (Q(c))

But again i haven't been able to find any examples of this online.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot. You can apply [**Universal Instantiation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) to a formula $\forall \varphi$.

Comment: Apologies, meant to say Universal Instantiation, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can't* apply Universal Instatiation to $\forall x \ P(x) \to \forall x \ Q(x)$

You can only apply Universal iIstantiation to a universal statement, and $\forall x \ P(x) \to \forall x \ Q(x)$ is not a universal statement ... it is a conditional statement

In general, you can never apply inference rules to a component statement of a larger statement.

Comment: A silly analogy: although you can conclude $q$ from $p \land q$, you cannot conclude $q \to p$ from $(p \land q) \to p$!

Comment: @MeesdeVries Ha!  That's the very example I always use myself: apply conjunction elimination to the antecedent! :)

Comment: So i can only apply rules of inference for quantifiers to a statement where everything is bound to a single quantifier? and if i have a statement such as ∀x P(x) ∧ ∃x Q(x), i cannot apply rules of inference for quantifiers? But i could still apply rules of inference eg simplication to get ∀x P(x) on its own then i can apply Universal Instantiation?

Comment: @Jamie Correct, correct, and correct!

Comment: Awesome thanks so much guys for the help and prompt replies, appreciate it! Have been stuck on this for days haha

Comment: @Jamie  Glad I could help! And, by the way, if you ever find yourself struggling to see how to prove that something follows from something else ...  maybe it is because it doesn't follow at all! :)

Comment: I forget that more often than i'd like! Thanks again